# Angular 4 Event Emitter not catching anything on subscribe

Tags: angular, eventemitter

A month ago I released a small [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-load-animation) that simply allows the display of a loading animation.

To do so my user would simply add `<ng-load></ng-load>` to their template and inject `LoadService` in their component and call `loadService.animate(true)` (or false).

On the library side of things I do the following:

In my service:

```
@Injectable()
export class LoadService {
  // My event emitter
  @Output() animating: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  // Method called by the user to display the animation,
  // emits the value passed as parameter
  public animate(val: boolean) {
    this.animating.emit(val);
  }

  getValue(): any {
    return this.animating;
  }
}
```

And in my component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'ng-load',
    templateUrl: './load.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./load.component.css']
})
export class LoadComponent implements OnInit {      
    animate: boolean;

    constructor(public loadService: LoadService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Listen to our event emitter
        this.loadService.getValue().subscribe((status: boolean) => {
            this.animate = status;
        });
    }
}
```

My `HTML` template simply has a `<div *ngIf="animate">` to show or hide the `CSS` animation.

So my event emitter emits what my user gives to `animate`, and the value of my boolean should change in my component, or so it did a month ago.

For some reason the subscribe on my Event Emitter does not catch anything.

Have `EventEmitters` changed? And am I using them in a wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues. First, @Output is used in components and not the services. Second, you're subscribing to getValue(), which doesn't return an Observable, subscribe can't work. Third, if you want your service to push the data to the subscribers, use Rx.Subject because EventEmitter is just another layer of abstraction on top of the Subject and its behavior may change in the future.

Comment: That's what I thought, after reading details about EventEmitters I now realize how my implementation can cause problems in the future (or right now, for that matter).

What would be the best approach in my case? To create an `Observable<boolean>` that my component will subscribe to?

Comment: In getValue() try returning Observable.of(this.animating) and remove @Output from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a primitive datatype `boolean` there might be situations where the reference of the object remains unchanged, so it will not trigger the subscriptions.

- So use a complex object

  ```
   let animation ={
        allowAnimation : true/false
   };
   this.animating.emit(animation); // might trigger the subscription
  ```
- Incremental Counter(number)

  ```
   this.animating.emit(i++);
  ```

Note: if the first case is not triggering then you can change the reference and emit which will cause the subscription to fire.

Comment: since when emit performs change detection??